# Finding the limit of $\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, limits

So I've tried to use Stirling's approximation and got that $\lim\frac{2n!}{n!}=\frac{1}{1}=1$

Any thoughts?

Comment: Assuming $n$ goes to infinity, that seems wrong, show us what you did.

Comment: What's the limit of n ?

Comment: This is correct if $n$ is approaching $0$.

Comment: Are you aware of $Stirling$ $Formula$ ?

Comment: I reckon $(2n)!/n!=(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n-1)(2n)$.

Comment: Really? That's not what I get using Stirling. Are you using $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac ne)^n$ ? Show your work!

Comment: @AnginaSeng : Simple but quite clear! Nice! +1 for you!

Comment: did you work out what 2n!/n! even is :(

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot n \cdot (n + 1) \cdot \dots \cdot 2n}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot n} = \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} (n+1) \cdot (n+2) \cdot \dots \cdot 2n = + \infty$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{2n!}{n!} = \frac{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)!}{n(n-1)!} \ge 2.\frac{2(n-1)!}{(n-1)!}$

So, $\frac{2n!}{n!} \ge 2^n$

$\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{2n!}{n!} \ge \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} 2^n = + \infty$